# Hide playback controls when adjusting volume windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio

So recently something weird happened with my PC. I don't know if it was caused by windows update(1903) or chrome.. But now when I adjust volume in chrome, this shows up:

[image]

earlier only volume panel used to appear, now some playback controls also show up which are really annoying.. Is there any way to just show volume panel and hide these playback controls? I searched in windows settings but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not from a Windows update, but rather from a Chrome update.  Updating to Chrome v75 seems to have added this issue.

You can prevent the media controls box from appearing by going to `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` and changing it to **Disabled**.  Be aware, though, that if you use media keys on your keyboard to control apps running in Chrome (Pandora, Spotify, YouTube, etc.) that this will cause them to be disabled.

[I have a question open about disabling the box without disabling the keys.](https://superuser.com/q/1449778/118184)  We'll see if it gets any answers.

Comment: It's not just Chrome - I use Firefox and it does it to me also.