# Chrome update v75 adds an obnoxious black box when adjusting volume in Windows

Tags: google-chrome, audio, keyboard

After Chrome updated to v75 recently, I found that anytime I changed volume using the volume keys on my computer, I got this large, annoying, black box next to my volume window:

[image]

I found out that you can disable this by going to `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` in Chrome and changing the flag from Default or Enabled to **Disabled**.  This does fix the problem of the box appearing, but now I can't use the multimedia keys on my keyboard to control apps running in Chrome (Pandora, YouTube, etc.).

Is there any way to prevent the appearance of the giant black chrome.exe media box that does not require disabling the media keys in Chrome?

Comment: Happens also in latest Firefox.

Comment: @fpmurphy You can disable it in FF by going to `about:config` and searching `media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled` and set it to **false**.  Still the same problem that it disables the media key use in the browser, but it seems to be the only way to get rid of the extra black box.